# jade templating syntax support for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, ide, pug

I have just starting using the nodejs templating engine jade. Unfortunately my IDE eclipse doesn't seem to have support for this syntax and is not highlighting correctly.

**Is it possible to add support for .jade files to eclipse?**

Comment: Sure, figure out how eclipse does syntax high lighting then add a lex or parsing file to support it. Alternatively use [this netbeans one](https://github.com/lumenlunae/jade-netbeans-syntax-highlighting) or use any vim jade syntax hightlighting plugin of choice.

Comment: How would I go about installing these syntax highlighters in eclipse?

Comment: you don't. The alternative suggest is use netbeans or vim as your editor/ide

Comment: Not quite Jade support but already a promising avenue: http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html

Answer (score 3):

As current lead of Nodeclipse effort www.nodeclipse.org I announce that Nodeclipse v0.12 has added Minimalist Jade Editor, see http://www.nodeclipse.org/history. Added just before release as I got sick of .jade to be opened outside of Eclipse.

- [#134](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/134) - [Minimalist Jade Editor](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.jade)
  idea is to define HTML tags and JavaScript keywords as words for highlight [in Word.java](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.jade/src/org/nodeclipse/enide/editors/jade/highlight/Words.java)
  and then use it together with EditBox

Nodeclipse scope is growing, now it has Gradle for Android and JavaScript in general that I want to work on for next iteration. Also looking for developers and company willing to support the project. Raise an issue on GitHub/Nodeclipse to continue.

Comment: I believe that Eclipse lacks basic editor functionality, that is coloring all possibly file formats. That done in most text editors.

Answer (score 2):

check if this helps

[Jade-syntax-highlight](https://github.com/aulphar/Jade-syntax-highlight-HRC)

Comment: I contacted the author before. He had no plans to continue the project. The next step would be get coloror source into GitHub as I just cannot open the site, see https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/140

Answer (score 0):

Follow the pattern used for adding [HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474096/using-haml-sass-with-eclipse) support to an Eclipse install, and find a lexer and colorizer for Jade.