# Can Eclipse Formatter be customized to avoid mangling sass (.scss)

Tags: eclipse, sass

I'm very happy with Eclipse over all and am using it and CLI (for NPM tidy and GIT) however I have noticed a couple of rather frustrating items when editing sass files (using .scss flavor, I haven't explored .sass flavor).

The first is minor, an inconvenience really and it is that anything following a "}" is displayed as green, I felt I could ignore this as it's a fairly straight-forward misapplication of a rule that does make sense in plain CSS.  But  CTRL+SHIFT+F breaks entirely, and I suspect it's for the s ame reason... it's doing things that do make sense in CSS but not in sass.  For example:

```
/* _structure.scss, include in style.scss 
html {
  height: 99%; 
  min-width: 18em; 
  max-width: 60em; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: $bg_dark;
}

.main {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  text-align: center;
  background-color: $bg_medium; 
  @include wb($bishop) {
    left : 10%;
    right: 10%;}
  @include wb ($queen) {
    left: 20%; 
    right: 20%;}
& h1 {
  top 2rem;
  color: $text_light; 
  font: { 
    size :    4rem; }
  line-height: 3rem; }
& h2 {
  color: $text_medium; 
  font: { 
    size : 3rem; }
  line-height: 7rem; }
}
```

which should change only very little becomes:

```
/* _structure.scss, include in style.scss 
html {
  height: 99%; min-width: 18em; max-width: 60em; margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  height: 100%; background-color: $bg_dark;
}

.main {
  position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; text-align: center;
  background-color: $bg_medium; @ include wb($bishop) { left : 10%;
  right: 10%;
}

@
include wb ($queen) {
  left: 20%; right: 20%;
}

&
h1 {top 2rem;
  color: $text_light; font: { size :    4rem;
}

line-height
:

3
rem
;


}
&
h2 {
  color: $text_medium; font: { size :   3rem;
}
line-height
:

7
rem
;

}
}
```

I did find this question:
[Is there an Eclipse editor for Sass's scss files or syntax coloring plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614612/is-there-an-eclipse-editor-for-sasss-scss-files-or-syntax-coloring-plugin)  which talks to part of the problem but doesn't resolve all of it.  I suspect that there is some way to enter into the xml that specifically governs this behaviour but as I'm neither hardcore XML nor hardcore eclipse I'd prefer a simpler solution.