# Using SASS for Java EE projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, css, eclipse, sass

I have already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474096/using-haml-sass-with-eclipse) question on SO but it is not the solution I'm looking for.

I'm a Java Web Developer, and so far for all CSS pre-processing needs, I've been using [Less](http://lesscss.org/) but now I want to move [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) due to its server-side rendering nature. But since it requires `gem` package manager and thus is more closer to Ruby then Java, how can I adopt it in my Java Web Applications that I develop in Eclipse?

Note that I'm not looking for Syntax Highlighting feature for `.scss`/`.sass` files in Eclipse, but I'd want that when my application is run on server from within Eclipse, the Sass is processed automatically and gets compiled to regular CSS. (Instead of running `sass --watch` outside Eclipse for each Sass file I create and save and include generated `.css` file separately in my web pages)

P.S. I'm using both Linux and Windows, but I primarily develop in Linux.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to have a sass --watch running?

Comment: @cimmanon: Its just that Eclipse doesn't recognize changes in a file that happened outside IDE, immediately, and I have to refresh project from project explorer and then need to re-run it, instead of just save-sass-file-and-refresh-browser scenario. I used `less.env = "development"` and `less.watch();` with Less previously, but I guess similar solution is not available in case of Sass, unless I'm on Mac and using something like CodeKit.

Answer (score 0):

Some years have passed, but finally now there is a viable solution:

https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper#-get-it-now

Integration of the Wild Web Developer with Eclipse is easy. It will compile your SCSS files to CSS files once they are changed. Besides this it supports lots of other features, such as code completion, code highlighting, validation and many more. You will need to install node.js to make use of all its features.